# I want to remove some text in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a multiple listbox, which shows the issues expire when either in negative or positive. I am facing error while selecting negative issues from the listbox.
[image]

I try to debug and found that there are some text that cause an error. The output looks like:

[image]

My code looks like:

```
var cleaneddata = task.Parent.DatabaseExpiresId.Replace("_0", string.Empty);                                      
int index = cleaneddata.LastIndexOf("_");
if (index > 0)
{
    cleaneddata = cleaneddata.Substring(0, index);
}
```

I only need -4, -6 as a input. Is there any methods to remove that unwanted text from the list.

Thanks

Comment: You should split the string by `,` and then loop thru the collection and take first two characters of each string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Id`s of each list item the numeric value, and only pass *those* through. Alternatively, parse the complete string to pull out the `Id`s.

For example:

```
-4_Issue 71,-6_Issue 69,
```

to:

```
[-4,-6]
```

you could do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string inVal = "-4_Issue 71,-6_Issue 69,";
        var parsed = ParsePhrase(inVal);
        Console.WriteLine($"parsed: {string.Join(",", parsed)}");
    }
    
    public static List<int> ParsePhrase(string inString){
        Console.WriteLine($"inString: {inString}");
        
        var outList = new List<int>();
        
        foreach(var item in inString.Split(',')){
            if(item.IndexOf("_") < 0)
                continue;
            
            var val = item.Substring(0,item.IndexOf("_"));
            int? valInt = int.TryParse(val, out var outVal)? outVal:null;
            if(valInt != null)
                outList.Add(valInt.Value);
        }
        
        return outList;
    }
}
```

output:

> inString: -4_Issue 71,-6_Issue 69,

> parsed: -4,-6

see:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DBfL2c